# Get Filestream from ZipArchive

Tags: c#, filestream, zip

I have a function that requires a Filestream as input.

I want to hand several Files to that function which I get from uploaded zip-Files.
Is it possible to create the Filestream without extracting the file to a temporary folder?

I imagin something like this:

```
string path = @"C:\somepathtomyzip";
string filepath = "nameofimagefile"
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(path))
{
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.GetEntry(file_path);

    //generate Filestream from entry

    myFunction(filestreamIneed);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ZipArchiveEntry.Open()` and copy the output from the returned `Stream` instance to a `FileStream` instance:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(path))
{
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.GetEntry(file_path);

     var memoryStream = return entry.Open();

     using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
     {
         memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream); // fileStream is not populated
     }
}
```

Comment: I get an Object of Type Stream (not MemoryStream) and I need Filestream.